# How to properly pass text file to search the data there?

Tags: python, file, google-app-engine, parsing

I have the file which contains the list of telephone number ranges and their owners (names of mobile operators) - http://www.rossvyaz.ru/opendata/7710549038-Rosnumbase/Kody_DEF-9kh.csv:

```
900;1940000;1949999;10000;Sky-1800
916;0;9999999;10000000;Mobile TeleSystems
917;0;29999;30000;Mobile TeleSystems
```

And I will have new phone numbers each week (in the format like +79161234567). So, I should detect their operators. So, I am planning to download updated list each week and then to match phones I have against this list.
The main question is how to do it effectively. Once I've downloaded the file, what is the best way to keep that in memory and then search for the mobile operator?

The first idea is to read the file line by line, parse it, compare DEF (`if '916' == def_from_the_line`), if so, then compare the range (`if 1234567>=range_start_from_the_line and 1234566<=range_end_from_the_line`), but it will not be quite effective (taken into consideration that I will have to look for several phone numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a data structure that you could use:

```
from collections import defaultdict

operators = defaultdict(list)
for line in open('data').readlines():
    pre, begin, end, _, operator_name = line.split(None,4)
    operators[pre].append((int(begin),int(end),operator_name))
```

So now `operators` is a dictionary whose keys are the prefixes (900, 916, 917) and whose values are lists of triples : begin of range, end of range, and name of operator. Now you can save that data to disk to avoid parsing the file again and again.

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(operators, open("operators", "wb"))
```

When you get a new number, just reload the `operators` object and leave it in memory.

```
operators = pickle.load(open("operators", "r"))
```

Then, the following function will parse the new number and find which range it fits in:

```
def get_operator(number, operators):
    pre = number[2:5]
    suf = int(number[5:])
    for begin, end, name in operators[pre]:
        if begin <= suf <= end:
            return name.strip()
    return Null


print get_operator("+79161234567", operators)
```

The above prints `Mobile TeleSystems`

Comment: Many thanks. This is what I was looking for (I've modified it a little, since I download the file with `urlfetch`).